# Ember.js array as model's property

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Cheers!
I have some model, and one attribute of it is an array, but for some reasons (I use mongoDB on the server and it's problem with embedded models and ember-data) I can't do somthing like this:

```
App.Foo = DS.Model.extend({
  ...
  numbers: DS.hasMany('App.Bar')
)};

App.Bar = DS.Model.extend({
  ...
  number: DS.attr('number')
});
```

I need something like this:

```
App.Bar = DS.Model.extend({
  numbers: DS.attr('array')
});
```

But there is no array type of attributes in ember-data, how to be?

Comment: We need more information here. I think you are looking for a transform.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I found that actually you can have array properties out of the box by just not specifying a type.

```
#coffeescript

AskuWhiteLabel.SomeModel = DS.Model.extend
    some_ids: DS.attr()
```

I'm using this, and when I do this

```
myModel.set('some_ids', [1,2,3])
myModel.save()
```

The payload to the server is indeed my array as is.

Comment: Cheers, Andy, I asked this question on Feb 14 '13, so it's it could be outdated or smth.

Comment: @nikita no problem! Yeah I didn't find any documentation around it, I think I just tried it out. Hope it helps!

Comment: Yeah it helps me though :D

Answer (score 3):

For those, who have the same problem as me:
check out this answer:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/13884238/1662820

Or you can pass embedded models with hasMany relation and set custom primary key for embedded model in the adapter ('number' in my case). Look at this tests:

> https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/tests/integration/embedded/embedded_without_ids_test.js

Answer (score 2):

```
anArrayAttr: DS.attr('raw', { defaultValue: function() { return []; } })
```

From my awesome colleague 'Theron Humiston'

Comment: what is `raw` ? did you define custom transform?

Comment: DS.attr() on its own was enough