# Ember: can't display my data

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data

I can't understand why I cannot visualize my data. If I check with the google app and in the console (App.model.store) they are there but whenever I try to insert them in Handlebars, nothing happen.
the more confusing thing is that no error is display.

I prepared a simplify version of my app to post here:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <header>
    <ul>
        <li>{{#linkTo "cal"}} Home {{/linkTo}}</li>
        <li>{{#linkTo "location"}} location {{/linkTo}}</li>
    </ul>
</header>
<section class="content">

    {{outlet}}

</div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="cal">
  <div class="calendar">
      Hello!!!
    <h2>{{name}}</h2>
  </div>
</script> 

window.WebCalendar = Ember.Application.create();

WebCalendar.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();

WebCalendar.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12,
    adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});

/////// ROUTER
WebCalendar.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('index', {path: '/'}, function() {
        this.resource("cal", {path: '/'});
        this.resource("location", {path: '/location'});
    });
});



WebCalendar.CalRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return this.store.find('cal').toArray();
    }
});


////// Model
WebCalendar.Cal = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    days_label: DS.attr('string'),
    months_label: DS.attr('string'),
    days_per_month: DS.attr('number'),
    current_date: DS.attr('date')

});


WebCalendar.Cal.FIXTURES = [
    {   
    "id": 1,
        "name": "Jhon",

        "days_label": ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],

        "months_label": ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April',
                         'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September',
                         'October', 'November', 'December'],

        "days_per_month": [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31],
    }
];
```

I'm really not sure about my JSON file also..
Any help is really appreciate!

Here the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bemLk?editors=101)

p.s. If you also have any suggestion how to properly check ember in the console, will be super!

Comment: You can use ember-inspector to check your Ember app https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi?hl=en

Comment: yes i'm already using it but most of the time isn't very helpful :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making a `find()` call is to find all models that are cals and so is going to return an array anyway so no need for `toArray()`
 Given that an array is being returned you need to loop through that array to find the name so code should be:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="cal">
  <div class="calendar">
    Hello!!!
    {{#each cal in model}}
    <h2>{{cal.name}}</h2>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</script> 


WebCalendar.CalRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return this.store.find('cal');
    }
});
```

also in your model your `days_label, months_label, days_per_month` are defined as strings but in your json they are arrays.

`Ember.Logger.log();` will log things o the console for you:
ex

```
WebCalendar.CalRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        model: function(){
        var cals = this.store.find('cal');
        Ember.Logger.log(cals);
            return cals
        }
    });
```

Comment: I used .toArray() because i cannot see clearly my data in the console and when I tryed with that they where there very clear so I thought was a simplification. About model defined as string, actually i search a lot for how can i defined them and I finded just number and string so I guessed that I cannot defined as Array but now i know Yeyy! Thanks! Last I tried already to use each but it was complaining that no Array was there. And now, after fixing all the others small problems, I can see a better error msg: My Controller is defined as ObjectController instead it ask for An ArrayController

Comment: Basically: Thank you very much!! :) One last question: how can I access to one day of the week for example? I thought I just should do {{days_label[2]}} but it doesn't really work

Comment: looking at your code pen you cant do DS.attr('array') - ember wont understand it - leave them as ('strings') to get a day of the week you would need to do a computed property

Comment: Right, i just found it a way to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168570/how-to-represent-arrays-within-ember-data-models/13884238#13884238 that' shoudl solve my problem

Comment: glad to hear and glad i could help