# How to represent complex objects in Ember models?

Tags: ember.js

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168570/how-to-represent-arrays-within-ember-data-models) explains how to store an array in an Ember model, but how could it be done with a custom object, which also isn't supported natively [supported, according to the Guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/defining-models/).

This is an example of the object that I am building

```
obj[0] = {"timeInMinutes": ">120", "occurrences": 24 };
obj[1] = {"timeInMinutes": "90-120","occurrences": 69 };
obj[2] = {"timeInMinutes": "60-90", "occurrences":  53 };
obj[3] = {"timeInMinutes": "30-60", "occurrences": 35  };
obj[4] = {"timeInMinutes": "0-30", "occurrences": 24 };
```

Update.

Using the information provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168570/how-to-represent-arrays-within-ember-data-models), I was able to create an array attribute on my model along with several other values, but I also want to be able to create `DS.attr('object')` attribute to be used like this. To create an object type, do I need to use a `DS.Transform.extend({` as was done with the array in the linked to SO answer?

```
 App.Index = DS.Model.extend({
    names: DS.attr('array'),
    country: DS.attr('string'),
    statistics: DS.attr('object')
```

Comment: You linked to the guide about Ember Data models. Are you using Ember Data?

Comment: yes, i'm using EmberData as it's a dependency for the localstorage adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the property to be a primitive object and not an Ember Object then you can do the following:

```
ObjectTransform = DS.Transform.extend({
  deserialize: function(serialized) { return serialized; },
  serialize: function(deserialized) { return deserialized; }
});
```

This is assuming that you don't need to change the object at all after it comes in over the wire.

Comment: so how do I use it when setting up my model? like this?  ```App.myModel = Ember.Model.extend({
    name : DS.attr('string'),
    someObject : DS.attr('object')
}```

Comment: I have the exact same setup, but have used the naming `RawTransform` and `DS.attr('raw')`. I assume that using the word `object` will work too. Note that it's not just for objects. Anything that doesn't need serialization and deserialization can be used in this way, including arrays of primitives or arrays of objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using Ember Data, you’ll have to structure your models in an Ember Data-compatible way. You could have a parent `Object` (surely has a better name, but you didn’t explain your domain at all) that `hasMany` `TimespanOccurrence`s or the like.

Comment: I'm sorry, this isn't clear to me. Maybe I didn't provide enough info. I updated the OP in the hopes that you could provide a bit more detail. Thanks in advance